# Trying to find the title of a SF book, about a US and Russian war

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this book in 2016. It starts out with how the author was inspired by hypothetical sciences in the early 80's.

The book is about, the US being afraid that the Russians had set off a nuke.

So a base was sort of sunk into the earth. But here's the thing, they are solid to each other, but like ghost. The are able to occupy the same space as solid matter.

It becomes a yearly thing to try and climb a ladder back to the surface. 
The main character finally does and he Russians had taken over the United States and he is invisible to the Russians at first.

The cover shows a guy, climbing out of a hole in the ground. In a field of wheat being harvested by a huge red Russian tractor.

Comment: Did the tractor have CCCP stencilled on it? This sounds very familiar - hard think time!

Comment: yes, And google search. Really sucks, I've been looking for some time now.

Answer (score 8):

[Duende Meadow](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?19266) by [Paul Cook](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?3017).

From the cover:

> Six centuries after the Last War, the battle for America has just begun.
>
> For six long centuries after mankind’s Last War, a handful of survivors dwelled in a place of eternal twilight below the fields of Kansas. Transformed into duendes, ghost-like beings, by the fields of organic energy which protected them, they waited for nature to heal the wounds of the Earth. But when, at last, they reached the light, they found their land in the hands of their age-old enemies…

[image]

Comment: Nice! That looks like it hits all of the points.

Comment: Yes, this is it. Thank you. It is a very good read imo.

Comment: @deanhalloway Please remember to accept this answer (click the checkmark on the left) to mark it as correct.